# How do I enlarge the mouse pointer/cursor?

Tags: 11.04, mouse, customization

In Ubuntu 10.10 I could enlarge the mouse pointer. In Ubuntu 11.04 I cannot find the option.

Answer (score 3):

Due to a [bug in compiz](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/459647) the mouse pointer size or pointer theme **can be changed in Unity but may only work in some circumstances** (e.g. Firefox).

For **GNOME classic and Unity** desktop the option to change the mouse pointer size or style is found in *System Settings -> Appearance -> Theme -> Customize -> Pointer*:

[image]

Push the slider at the bottom to the desired size.

Comment: Thanks, solution seems to work. I can find where to adjust the setting. However in Firefox pointer is large but outside Firefox when i am hovering over my desktop the pointer is smail. (original size). Is this an bug?

Comment: I believe this may be a part of the compiz bug I mentioned in the first line - on my box any enlarged pointer is on terminal window only.

Comment: I think you're wright. When i boot with no desktop effects in Gnome classic everything works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Workarounds for the bug in Unity are now referred to on the [bug page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/459647) however your mileage may vary.

None of them had any positive effect in my system.

Unfortunate fail for Ubuntu, given that this is a longstanding issue, degrades the claim that Ubuntu is flexible or mainstream ready.